# Is power received reflected off a surface dependant on both the incident and emitted angles?

Tags: optics, radiometry

I am trying to calculate the incident power into a detector as reflected from a small illuminated Lambertian surface. Basically I am looking for a check of my calculations as I am not confident that both incident and emitted angles ($\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$) should affect the power received by the detector.

[image: Light reflected off surface]

Say the surface with area $A_s$ is illuminated from the sun with an irradiance of $I$ in W/m^2. From the equation on slide 8 of [these lecture slides](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15462-f09/www/lec/lec8.pdf), the radiance from this surface is: $$L_s = \frac{\rho}{\pi} I \cos \theta_1$$

The power received by the detector with area $A_d$ will be: $$P_d = L_s A_{sf} \Omega_d$$
Assuming that the distance from surface to detector, $r$, is much larger than the size of either area, we can substitute $\Omega_d = A_{df}/r^2$. (I am basing this off of [these other slides](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~elm/Teaching/vision570/Lecture%204b.pdf) (refer simplifying assumption on slide 17) 
$$P_d = L_s A_{sf} A_{df} / r^2$$ 
In the above equations I am using subscript $f$ to designate that the area is foreshortened by the angle of the other surface. Assuming that the detector is face on to the on coming ray: $A_{df} = A_d$. The foreshortened surface area is: $A_{sf} = A_s\cos\theta_2$ so 
$$P_d = L_s A_{d} A_{s} \cos\theta_2 / r^2$$
Substituting in the radiance from the surface $L_s$:
$$P_d = \frac{\rho}{\pi} I A_{d} A_{s} \cos \theta_1 \cos\theta_2 / r^2$$

Furthermore, if we take As as an infinitesimal area of a surface, I believe we can integrate the equation over the surface like so:
$$Pd = \frac{\rho I A_{d}}{\pi r^2} \iint_S \cos \theta_1 \cos\theta_2 dS$$
This tells us that the power recieved from a Lambertian surface is dependent on both the angle to the emitter and observer. However, I have read in various sources, e.g. from the wikipedia page on Lambert's cosine law: `...although the radiance of the surface depends on the angle from the normal to the illuminating source, it will not depend on the angle from the normal to the observer.` My thinking is that the angle from normal to observer comes into the equation when we actually calculate the power at the observer. I am hoping someone can back me up or poke a hole in my reasoning.